# javascript dynamic drop down list - two forms depend of one

Tags: javascript

I want to create a dynamic drop down list with javascript.
Right now it works like this:
- if I choose first option, then second, then third.

I want to change this code to:
- when I choose first option, it shows second and third option in the same time(second and third option depends of first)

I want to do something like:
Choose name:
John Doe(first option)
Choose proffesion:
Dentist(second option)
Choose gender:
male(third option)

Is it possible?

Thanks for reply.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
var modelsArray = new Array(
   ["Chevy","","Camaro","Corvette","Impala"],
   ["Dodge","","Avenger","Challenger","Charger"],
   ["Ford","","Mustang","Shelby"]
);
var colorsArray = new Array(
   ["Camaro","","White","Black","Red"],
   ["Corvette","","White","Purple","Blue","Fawn"],
   ["Impala","","White","Black","Red","Chrome Yellow"],
   ["Avenger","","White","Acid Green","Alice Blue"],
   ["Challenger","","White","Violet","Blue-Green"],
   ["Charger","","White","Dark Pastel Red"],
   ["Mustang","","White","Debian red","Impala","Flame"],
   ["Shelby","","White","Deep Spring Bud"]
);
function populate1(s1,s2,s3){
var optionArray = [];
var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);
s2.innerHTML = "";
var s3 = document.getElementById(s3);
s3.innerHTML = "";
   for(var i = 0; i < modelsArray.length; i++){
      if(s1.value == modelsArray[i][0]){
         for(var x = 1; x < modelsArray[i].length; x++){
            optionArray.push(modelsArray[i][x]);
         }
      }
   }
   optionArray.sort();
   for(var option in optionArray){
      var newOption = document.createElement("option");
      newOption.value = optionArray[option];
      newOption.innerHTML = optionArray[option];
      s2.options.add(newOption);
   }
}
function populate2(s1,s2){
var optionArray = [];
var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);
s2.innerHTML = "";
   for(var i = 0; i < colorsArray.length; i++){
      if(s1.value == colorsArray[i][0]){
         for(var x = 1; x < colorsArray[i].length; x++){
            optionArray.push(colorsArray[i][x]);
         }
      }
   }
   optionArray.sort();
   for(var option in optionArray){
      var newOption = document.createElement("option");
      newOption.value = optionArray[option];
      newOption.innerHTML = optionArray[option];
      s2.options.add(newOption);
   }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Choose Your Car</h2>
<hr />
Choose Car Make:
<select id="slct1" name="slct1" onchange="populate1(this.id,'slct2','slct3')">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="Chevy">Chevy</option>
  <option value="Dodge">Dodge</option>
  <option value="Ford">Ford</option>
</select>
<hr />
Choose Car Model:
<select id="slct2" name="slct2" onchange="populate2(this.id,'slct3')"></select>
<hr />
Choose Car Color:
<select id="slct3" name="slct3"></select>
<hr />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/arcadeGandalf/jLmkha81/) which implements a rudimentary example.

You can create DOM event listeners to respond to the `change` event of the select elements. When these events are triggered, pass the value of the selected option to a function which can extract the models/colours from the data.

Ideally you will setup your server side code to return the data in a format such as:

```
{
    "makes": {
        "ford": {
            "models": {
                "focus": {
                    "colours": [
                        "blue",
                        "black"
                    ]
                },
                "probe": {
                    "colours": [
                        "green",
                        "grey"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using this data format you can easily drill down the object tree e.g.

```
carData.makes.ford.models.focus.colours
```

Once you have the data you can then use jQuery to append options to your select e.g.

```
    for (var model in models) {    
        $('select').append('<option value="' 
                                 + model + '">' + model + 
                                 '</option>');
    }
```

*EDIT: If you want to use the combination of the first two selects then you can do something like this:

```
var mapCombinations = {canada: {toronto: {mapName: "canada"}}};

var mapName = mapCombinations[selectValue1][selectValue2].mapName);

showMap(mapName);

function showMap(mapName) {
      // Call server to get map
    $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "http://yoururl.com/api/map/" + mapName,
       success: function(data){
           // display map
       }
    });
}
```

EDIT2: You can use the same principle if you want the third select to contain an action. I've replaced the colours array with actions. This third select will change depending on the first 2 select values.

[Updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arcadeGandalf/jLmkha81/1/) which doesn't use jquery.

You can then set up an event listener to process that action.

Comment: So how to make this 3 forms without jquery? And how it looks with this configuration which you edited? Can you show it on jsfiddle?

Comment: This with 2 options works, but doesn't show third value.(How to do it?)

Comment: The third option is showing for me after first two options are selected.

Comment: I want to show second and third option in the same time, when I choose first value.

Comment: I don't understand the use case for which this logic is going to be applied. But, if you're wanting to populate both selects then just modify the `populateModels` function to call `populateColours` and set the `currentModel` to one of the values.

Comment: I want to have 3 forms in one website, 2 will be next to, third will be on the bottom. I tried to do this what you said, and I doesn't work.

Comment: Try [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arcadeGandalf/jLmkha81/3/). When you select the country, the second options is populated with cities and the third is populated with maps.

Comment: Okay, that's nice. What if I have two or more countries? How to configure that?

Comment: Modify the data in the `countryDataResponse` object. You'll see the cities array. Modify that from `"cities":["toronto"]` to `"cities":["toronto", "*your new city*"]`

Comment: countryDataResponse: '{"countries":{"canada":{"cities":["toronto","amsterdam"], "maps": ["canada","Tokio"]}}
    {"Japan":{"cities":["Japan","Tokio"]}}',
I see how to change cities, I don't know how to add countries

Comment: Ah sorry, you can add a new country next to canada e.g. `{"countries":{"canada":{"cities":["toronto"], "maps": ["canada"]},"scotland":{"cities":["glasgow"], "maps": ["scotland"]}}}`. It's easier to read if you use a json lint tool such as http://jsonlint.com/.

Comment: This is quite a good reference for learning how to create JSON strings: http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/core-json

Comment: This script works fine, but if I choose first value, and then select second, there is a problem, that it doesn't refresh well(doesn't show for me good values in second and third form). I added 6 countries, and a few cities in each country and a few maps, and doesn't reset good.

Comment: [This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arcadeGandalf/jLmkha81/9/) works fine for me.

Comment: countryDataResponse: '{"countries":{"Austria":{"cities":["villach","wien","graz","linz","salzburg","innsbruck","klagenfurt"], "maps": ["canada"]},"scotland":{"cities":["glasgow"], "maps": ["scotland"]}}}',

I added this and it loads very bad.

Comment: What do you mean by very bad? The json works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I need to repeat third value all the time.
I try to give you an example.

1. First value = Country
2. Second value = City
3. Third value = option

And I want to do something like:
If First value = Canada then Second value = Toronto
If First value = Canada then Third value = Show canada map

Second Value and third value don't depend of themselve, only of first value.